# Columns changing when exporting from DBeaver to CSV

Tags: csv, export, dbeaver

When exporting from DBeaver to CSV , columns are changing their values,

6923987516040527433 is getting converted to 6.92405E+18, whereas date is changing from 2021-05-17 02:49:04 to '2021-05-17 02:49:04.948'

How can this transformation be avoided?

Comment: I just made a test here, on export to CSV I could DISABLE both the quoting and number formatting. My exported line looked like   `6923987516040527433;2021-05-17 02:49:04`  exactly as entered. Using latest version of DBeaver.

Comment: @MyICQ am using 21.1.0 version. I disabled both numeric formatting and disable formatting, still facing the issue. Is there anything else to be done?